# Elasticsearch: how to rank-high the exact match?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search item "vision" for one field but I just got results like "vision A", "vision B", "xx version","vision" etc by using match/match_phrace/term in the DSL.

What I want is the exact match "vision" should have the highest score and the items which contain "vision" should rank behind the exact match. The ranking should be:

```
vision > vision A > vision B > xx version
```

I checked [Elasticsearch match exact term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37529851/elasticsearch-match-exact-term) in which change the "index" to be "not_analyzed" is recognized to realize exact match. But in my case not only exact match but also the containing match is needed.

What can I do for this case? Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you can do to achieve this is to include a few constraints in q `bool/should` query in order to control the ranking.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "name": "vision"                  <--- match on vision
        }
      },
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "name.keyword": {               <--- boost exact matches on keyword field (i.e. "vision")
              "value": "vision",
              "boost": 3
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "prefix": {
            "name.keyword": {               <--- boost prefix matches on keyword field (i.e. "vision A" and "vision B"
              "value": "vision",
              "boost": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

- The first clause will match all documents which contain `vision` in their `name` field.
- The second clause will give a higher boost to documents whose `name.keyword` field contains exactly `vision`. `name.keyword` is usually a `keyword` field (formerly a `not_analyzed` `string` field).
- The third clause will give a slightly higher boost to documents whose `name.keyword` field starts with `vision`.

Comment: You are superfast

Comment: Thanks so much for Val! It solves the problem perfectly!

Comment: @Val How can we boost exact match in `query_string` where the field can be arbitrary, is there a way to boost in that case.

Comment: @NeerajJain feel free to ask a new question with your exact needs.

Comment: @Val Here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56898079/elastic-search-boost-results-with-exact-match-in-query-string-without-speci