# How to increase score for exact word/phrase match in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a index with movie franchises in them, and I would like the exact word/phrase matches to score higher. For example, if I search for `"Star Trek"` I want `"Star Trek"` to score highest (first result) followed by `"Star Trek Beyond"` and `"Star Trek Into Darkness"`.  Currently when I search for `"Star Trek"` I get the titles with additional words scoring higher. Is this possible and how?

Also is it possible to get the same results as described above if there is some additrional unmatched text around the search term, for example: `"(randomText) Star Trek (randomText)"`

Here are my settings/mappings:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 20
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title_english": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "raw": { "type": "keyword" },
          "space": { "type": "text", "analyzer": "whitespace" }
        },
        "analyzer": "autocomplete"
      },
      "title_native": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "raw": { "type": "keyword" },
          "space": { "type": "text", "analyzer": "whitespace" }
        },
        "analyzer": "autocomplete"
      },
      "title_romaji": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "raw": { "type": "keyword" },
          "space": { "type": "text", "analyzer": "whitespace" }
        },
        "analyzer": "autocomplete"
      },
      "title_synonyms": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "raw": { "type": "keyword" },
          "space": { "type": "text", "analyzer": "whitespace" }
        },
        "analyzer": "autocomplete"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my query:

```
'query': {
    'bool': {
        'must': {
            'multi_match': {
                'query': request.args.get('query'),
                'analyzer': 'standard',
                'fields': ['title_*']
            },
        },
        'should': [{
            'term': {
                'title_*.raw': {
                    'value': request.args.get('query'),
                    'boost': 3
                }
            }
        },
        {
            'prefix': {
                'title_*.raw': {
                    'value': request.args.get('query'),
                    'boost': 2
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53000901/elasticsearch-how-to-rank-high-the-exact-match . This post has the answer for your question

Comment: I tried that but it does not work for me. I updated my post adding my settings/mappings and query.