# Elastic Search: Boost Results with "Exact match" in "query_string" without specifying the field

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using `query_string` to search for records from Elastic,

Example Query :

```
GET /stories_qa/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Johnson && Johnson"
    }
  }
}
```

This query gives me relevant records, but the exact match record is not on top, I figured out on how we can boost records based on specific fields,  but in my case, I don't want to provide field and make search restrictive, Is there an option in ElasticSearch to achieve the same.

Comment: if you don't want to make your search restrictive/specific, it will be hard to make it precise. But maybe someone can give you some hints

Comment: Can you add at least two sample docs, mentioning the one that should be on top?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do something like below, but do thorough testing and test multiple scenarios before you move it to production.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "\"Karnataka Delhi\"",
                  "default_operator": "AND"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "Karnataka Delhi",
            "default_operator": "OR",
            "boost": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "Karnataka Delhi",
            "default_operator": "AND",
            "boost": 4
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's not working, giving the same result if I just use `"query_string"` without all this modification

Comment: @NeerajJain Sorry I've updated the query once again a few secs before. Could you try it once again.

Comment: it's still not working, It gives just 1 record, which is due to the exact match we are doing with `"\"Karnataka Delhi\""`

Comment: @NeerajJain Strange it just gives 1 record in your result. In that case I doubt if it is possible to do what you want, because of the way relevancy is calculated behind the scenes. You can only influence the relevancy to a certain extent by boosting values or forming some combination of clauses as I've mentioned in the answer otherwise, perhaps what we are trying to do simply breaks the very definition of relevancy. I tried with some sample documents in my index but yours must be very comprehensive ones. Perhaps that's why I see the results accordingly, which again is not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

It would help with examples, but you can use [`phrase_match` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) by adding double quote. If you add a boost to the `phrase_match` query you will be able to get to exact match ranked higher.

The following query should do what you want.

```
GET /stories_qa/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(\"Johnson && Johnson\")^2 OR (Johnson && Johnson)"
    }
  }
}
```