# Difference of Elasticsearch and Opensearch scoring between versions

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I'm trying to migrate from Elasticsearch v7.10.1 to Opensearch v2 and seeing some differences in scoring of records during searches between versions. The same difference is with elasticsearch v8.x.
Below is queries and responds to it for a clear understanding of the difference.
I'll be very grateful if someone can explain why this happens and how it is possible to avoid it.

```
elasticsearch v7.10.1/opensearch v1.x
----------
DELETE /test
=====
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
        "reason" : "no such index [test]",
        "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
        "resource.id" : "test",
        "index_uuid" : "_na_",
        "index" : "test"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
    "reason" : "no such index [test]",
    "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
    "resource.id" : "test",
    "index_uuid" : "_na_",
    "index" : "test"
  },
  "status" : 404
}


PUT /test
{
    "mappings":{
      "properties":{
        "id":{"type":"keyword"},
        "en_title":{
          "type":"text",
          "analyzer":"fulltext_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer":"standard",
          "fields":{
            "keyword":{"type":"keyword"}
          }
          
        }
        
      }
      
    },
    "settings":{
      "analysis":{
        "filter":{
          "ngram_filter":{"type":"ngram","min_gram":1,"max_gram":10}},"analyzer":{"fulltext_analyzer":{"type":"custom","tokenizer":"standard","char_filter":["html_strip"],"filter":["lowercase","asciifolding","ngram_filter"]}},"tokenizer":{"my_edge_ngram_tokenizer":{"type":"edge_ngram","min_gram":"1","max_gram":"10"}}},"index.max_ngram_diff":10}}
=====
{
  "acknowledged" : true,
  "shards_acknowledged" : true,
  "index" : "test"
}



GET /test
=====
{
  "test" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "en_title" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          },
          "analyzer" : "fulltext_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer" : "standard"
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "max_ngram_diff" : "10",
        "routing" : {
          "allocation" : {
            "include" : {
              "_tier_preference" : "data_content"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "provided_name" : "test",
        "creation_date" : "1707491245697",
        "analysis" : {
          "filter" : {
            "ngram_filter" : {
              "type" : "ngram",
              "min_gram" : "1",
              "max_gram" : "10"
            }
          },
          "analyzer" : {
            "fulltext_analyzer" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding",
                "ngram_filter"
              ],
              "char_filter" : [
                "html_strip"
              ],
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "standard"
            }
          },
          "tokenizer" : {
            "my_edge_ngram_tokenizer" : {
              "type" : "edge_ngram",
              "min_gram" : "1",
              "max_gram" : "10"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "bwWeAQvhRrW0yVXGOaUHNw",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "7100199"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


POST /test/_doc
{
  "en_title": "Ami"
}
=====
{
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "5-9pjo0Bv6LnPPrbp2Mi",
  "_version" : 1,
  "result" : "created",
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_seq_no" : 0,
  "_primary_term" : 1
}


POST /test/_doc
{
  "en_title":"Umami"
}
=====
{
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "6O9qjo0Bv6LnPPrbDmNQ",
  "_version" : 1,
  "result" : "created",
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_seq_no" : 1,
  "_primary_term" : 1
}


{
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "6e9qjo0Bv6LnPPrbkmPN",
  "_version" : 1,
  "result" : "created",
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_seq_no" : 2,
  "_primary_term" : 1
}

=====
{
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "6e9qjo0Bv6LnPPrbkmPN",
  "_version" : 1,
  "result" : "created",
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_seq_no" : 2,
  "_primary_term" : 1
}


GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Ami",
      "fields": ["en_title"],
      "fuzziness": 2, 
      "prefix_length": 3
    }
  }
}
=====
{
  "took" : 603,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.2153281,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5-9pjo0Bv6LnPPrbp2Mi",
        "_score" : 0.2153281,
        "_source" : {
          "en_title" : "Ami"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6O9qjo0Bv6LnPPrbDmNQ",
        "_score" : 0.2153281,
        "_source" : {
          "en_title" : "Umami"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6e9qjo0Bv6LnPPrbkmPN",
        "_score" : 0.2153281,
        "_source" : {
          "en_title" : "Samira"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}


POST /test/_explain/6e9qjo0Bv6LnPPrbkmPN
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Ami",
      "fields": ["en_title"],
      "fuzziness": 2, 
      "prefix_length": 3
    }
  }
}
=====
{
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "6e9qjo0Bv6LnPPrbkmPN",
  "matched" : true,
  "explanation" : {
    "value" : 0.2153281,
    "description" : "weight(en_title:ami in 2) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
    "details" : [
      {
        "value" : 0.2153281,
        "description" : "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
        "details" : [
          {
            "value" : 2.2,
            "description" : "boost",
            "details" : [ ]
          },
          {
            "value" : 0.13353139,
            "description" : "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
            "details" : [
              {
                "value" : 3,
                "description" : "n, number of documents containing term",
                "details" : [ ]
              },
              {
                "value" : 3,
                "description" : "N, total number of documents with field",
                "details" : [ ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "value" : 0.7329843,
            "description" : "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
            "details" : [
              {
                "value" : 1.0,
                "description" : "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                "details" : [ ]
              },
              {
                "value" : 1.2,
                "description" : "k1, term saturation parameter",
                "details" : [ ]
              },
              {
                "value" : 0.75,
                "description" : "b, length normalization parameter",
                "details" : [ ]
              },
              {
                "value" : 1.0,
                "description" : "dl, length of field",
                "details" : [ ]
              },
              {
                "value" : 14.0,
                "description" : "avgdl, average length of field",
                "details" : [ ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}



elasticsearch v8.0/opensearch v2
----------
DELETE /test
=====
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
        "reason" : "no such index [test]",
        "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
        "resource.id" : "test",
        "index_uuid" : "_na_",
        "index" : "test"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
    "reason" : "no such index [test]",
    "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
    "resource.id" : "test",
    "index_uuid" : "_na_",
    "index" : "test"
  },
  "status" : 404
}



PUT /test
{
    "mappings":{
      "properties":{
        "id":{"type":"keyword"},
        "en_title":{
          "type":"text",
          "analyzer":"fulltext_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer":"standard",
          "fields":{
            "keyword":{"type":"keyword"}
          }
          
        }
        
      }
      
    },
    "settings":{
      "analysis":{
        "filter":{
          "ngram_filter":{"type":"ngram","min_gram":1,"max_gram":10}},"analyzer":{"fulltext_analyzer":{"type":"custom","tokenizer":"standard","char_filter":["html_strip"],"filter":["lowercase","asciifolding","ngram_filter"]}},"tokenizer":{"my_edge_ngram_tokenizer":{"type":"edge_ngram","min_gram":"1","max_gram":"10"}}},"index.max_ngram_diff":10}}
=====
{
  "acknowledged" : true,
  "shards_acknowledged" : true,
  "index" : "test"
}


GET /test
=====
{
  "test" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "en_title" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          },
          "analyzer" : "fulltext_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer" : "standard"
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "max_ngram_diff" : "10",
        "routing" : {
          "allocation" : {
            "include" : {
              "_tier_preference" : "data_content"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "provided_name" : "test",
        "creation_date" : "1707487806273",
        "analysis" : {
          "filter" : {
            "ngram_filter" : {
              "type" : "ngram",
              "min_gram" : "1",
              "max_gram" : "10"
            }
          },
          "analyzer" : {
            "fulltext_analyzer" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding",
                "ngram_filter"
              ],
              "char_filter" : [
                "html_strip"
              ],
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "standard"
            }
          },
          "tokenizer" : {
            "my_edge_ngram_tokenizer" : {
              "type" : "edge_ngram",
              "min_gram" : "1",
              "max_gram" : "10"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "XKHOE07qSgqSzAZAsAu2bQ",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "8000099"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /test/_doc
{
  "en_title": "Ami"
}
=====
{
  "_index" : "test",
  "_id" : "MpU1jo0BqQ4sSw1pFnoV",
  "_version" : 1,
  "result" : "created",
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_seq_no" : 0,
  "_primary_term" : 1
}


POST /test/_doc
{
  "en_title":"Umami"
}
=====
{
  "_index" : "test",
  "_id" : "M5U1jo0BqQ4sSw1pjnpt",
  "_version" : 1,
  "result" : "created",
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_seq_no" : 1,
  "_primary_term" : 1
}



POST /test/_doc
{
  "en_title":"Samira"
}
=====
{
  "_index" : "test",
  "_id" : "NJU1jo0BqQ4sSw1p23rk",
  "_version" : 1,
  "result" : "created",
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_seq_no" : 2,
  "_primary_term" : 1
}


GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Ami",
      "fields": ["en_title"],
      "fuzziness": 2, 
      "prefix_length": 3
    }
  }
}
=====
{
  "took" : 323,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.4306562,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_id" : "NJU1jo0BqQ4sSw1p23rk",
        "_score" : 0.4306562,
        "_source" : {
          "en_title" : "Samira"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_id" : "MpU1jo0BqQ4sSw1pFnoV",
        "_score" : 0.2153281,
        "_source" : {
          "en_title" : "Ami"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_id" : "M5U1jo0BqQ4sSw1pjnpt",
        "_score" : 0.2153281,
        "_source" : {
          "en_title" : "Umami"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}


POST /test/_explain/KpXxjY0BqQ4sSw1pBnqW
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Ami",
      "fields": ["en_title"],
      "fuzziness": 2, 
      "prefix_length": 3
    }
  }
}
=====
{
  "_index" : "test",
  "_id" : "NJU1jo0BqQ4sSw1p23rk",
  "matched" : true,
  "explanation" : {
    "value" : 0.4306562,
    "description" : "sum of:",
    "details" : [
      {
        "value" : 0.2153281,
        "description" : "weight(en_title:ami in 2) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
        "details" : [
          {
            "value" : 0.2153281,
            "description" : "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
            "details" : [
              {
                "value" : 2.2,
                "description" : "boost",
                "details" : [ ]
              },
              {
                "value" : 0.13353139,
                "description" : "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                "details" : [
                  {
                    "value" : 3,
                    "description" : "n, number of documents containing term",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 3,
                    "description" : "N, total number of documents with field",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "value" : 0.7329843,
                "description" : "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                "details" : [
                  {
                    "value" : 1.0,
                    "description" : "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 1.2,
                    "description" : "k1, term saturation parameter",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 0.75,
                    "description" : "b, length normalization parameter",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 1.0,
                    "description" : "dl, length of field",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 14.0,
                    "description" : "avgdl, average length of field",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "value" : 0.14355206,
        "description" : "weight(en_title:amir in 2) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
        "details" : [
          {
            "value" : 0.14355206,
            "description" : "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
            "details" : [
              {
                "value" : 1.4666666,
                "description" : "boost",
                "details" : [ ]
              },
              {
                "value" : 0.13353139,
                "description" : "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                "details" : [
                  {
                    "value" : 3,
                    "description" : "n, number of documents containing term",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 3,
                    "description" : "N, total number of documents with field",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "value" : 0.7329843,
                "description" : "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                "details" : [
                  {
                    "value" : 1.0,
                    "description" : "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 1.2,
                    "description" : "k1, term saturation parameter",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 0.75,
                    "description" : "b, length normalization parameter",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 1.0,
                    "description" : "dl, length of field",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 14.0,
                    "description" : "avgdl, average length of field",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "value" : 0.07177603,
        "description" : "weight(en_title:amira in 2) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
        "details" : [
          {
            "value" : 0.07177603,
            "description" : "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
            "details" : [
              {
                "value" : 0.7333333,
                "description" : "boost",
                "details" : [ ]
              },
              {
                "value" : 0.13353139,
                "description" : "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                "details" : [
                  {
                    "value" : 3,
                    "description" : "n, number of documents containing term",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 3,
                    "description" : "N, total number of documents with field",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "value" : 0.7329843,
                "description" : "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                "details" : [
                  {
                    "value" : 1.0,
                    "description" : "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 1.2,
                    "description" : "k1, term saturation parameter",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 0.75,
                    "description" : "b, length normalization parameter",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 1.0,
                    "description" : "dl, length of field",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 14.0,
                    "description" : "avgdl, average length of field",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}


POST /test/_explain/MpU1jo0BqQ4sSw1pFnoV
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Ami",
      "fields": ["en_title"],
      "fuzziness": 2, 
      "prefix_length": 3
    }
  }
}
=====
{
  "_index" : "test",
  "_id" : "MpU1jo0BqQ4sSw1pFnoV",
  "matched" : true,
  "explanation" : {
    "value" : 0.2153281,
    "description" : "sum of:",
    "details" : [
      {
        "value" : 0.2153281,
        "description" : "weight(en_title:ami in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
        "details" : [
          {
            "value" : 0.2153281,
            "description" : "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
            "details" : [
              {
                "value" : 2.2,
                "description" : "boost",
                "details" : [ ]
              },
              {
                "value" : 0.13353139,
                "description" : "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                "details" : [
                  {
                    "value" : 3,
                    "description" : "n, number of documents containing term",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 3,
                    "description" : "N, total number of documents with field",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "value" : 0.7329843,
                "description" : "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                "details" : [
                  {
                    "value" : 1.0,
                    "description" : "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 1.2,
                    "description" : "k1, term saturation parameter",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 0.75,
                    "description" : "b, length normalization parameter",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 1.0,
                    "description" : "dl, length of field",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 14.0,
                    "description" : "avgdl, average length of field",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The solution was found here:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53000901/elasticsearch-how-to-rank-high-the-exact-match?fbclid=IwAR2c3TLA7KkjmBJALN5CCIvXYJqnONTcVhVwOg9Ho501uw9r56y66QcRNK4)